# How to collect logcat logs for a certain amount of time

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I'm trying to collect some logs in powershell with logcat on a device for a certain number of seconds (60). I can't find any commands or parameters that logcat takes to end a log?

This is what I have right now:
`adb logcat -v tag | select-string TEST > C:Temp/test.txt`.

How can I grab logs just for 60 seconds and have it end and save to the file specified?